# Functions not defined in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
data() {
    return {
        arrayToBeSorted: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
        isManipulatingArray: false,

        shuffleButtonText: "Shuffle!",

        sortAlgorithms: [
            { id: 1, name: "Bubble sort", fn: bubbleSort },
            { id: 2, name: "Selection sort", fn: selectionSort },
            { id: 3, name: "Insertion sort", fn: insertionSort },
        ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
      sort: function (Algorithm) {
          this.Algorithm.fn();
      },
      show: function() {
        console.log("shuffle!");
      },
      bubbleSort: function() {
        console.log("bubble!");
      },
      selectionSort: function() {
        console.log("selection!");
      },
      insertionSort: function() {
        console.log("insertion!");
      },
  }
```

```html
<div class="buttons-container">
         <button class="button" v-for="Algorithm in sortAlgorithms" :key="Algorithm.id" v-on:click="Algorithm.fn">{{ Algorithm.name }}</button>
</div>
```

When I hit the button I want the respective method to be invoked via the sort function but I'm getting an error of function not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `this` context

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      arrayToBeSorted: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
      isManipulatingArray: false,

      shuffleButtonText: "Shuffle!",

      sortAlgorithms: [{
          id: 1,
          name: "Bubble sort",
          fn: this.bubbleSort
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Selection sort",
          fn: this.selectionSort
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Insertion sort",
          fn: this.insertionSort
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sort: function(Algorithm) {
      Algorithm.fn();
    },
    show: function() {
      console.log("shuffle!");
    },
    bubbleSort: function() {
      console.log("bubble!");
    },
    selectionSort: function() {
      console.log("selection!");
    },
    insertionSort: function() {
      console.log("insertion!");
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="buttons-container">
    <button class="button" v-for="Algorithm in sortAlgorithms" :key="Algorithm.id" v-on:click="Algorithm.fn">{{ Algorithm.name }}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```